# Convert ST_POINT subtype to ST_GEOMETRY supertype?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, query-layer, st-geometry

*Oracle 18c; ArcGIS 10.7.1*

I have a query that produces an [ST_POINT](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm) column:

```
--Mimics the SDO_GEOMETRY get_vertices function 
--https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_util-getvertices.htm

create or replace view road_vertices as (
select
    road_id,
    sde.st_pointn(shape,n.num) vertex_st_point
from
    roads s
cross join
    numbers n
where
    n.num <= sde.st_numpoints(shape)
)
```

That query works fine in when I run it in an SQL client.

---

**Problem:**

I run into various issues when I try to use the query in ArcGIS Desktop. For example, when I try to use the query as a layer in ArcMap, I get an error from the ST_POINT shape column:

[image]

```
Warning

Could not add the specified data object to the map.
Wrong column type[Invalid Geometry Storage Type]
```

Note: ESRI has documented the problem here:

[Unable to define a query layer in ArcGIS where the data source uses an st_geometry subtype in Oracle](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011333)

But that article doesn't tell us what the actual fix is.

---

**Ugly Fix:**

If I convert the ST_POINT subtype to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype, then I can add the query to ArcMap without issue.

```
sde.st_geometry(sde.st_astext(   sde.st_pointn(shape,n.num)   ,26917) as vertex_st_geom
```

The only way I've found to do that is to convert the the ST_POINT to WKT and then to ST_GEOMETRY.

However, in my opinion, it seems pretty backwards to use `sde.st_astext` and `sde.st_geometry` to perform the conversion (and adds a significant cost).

---

**Question:**

Is there a cleaner way to convert the ST_POINT subtype to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype?

Answer (score 1):

I can use Oracle's [TREAT()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TREAT.html#GUID-037C0CD3-C256-4A02-80E0-C6F15147C5BF) function to convert the ST_POINT subtype to the ST_GEOMETRY supertype.

```
treat(sde.st_pointn(shape,n.num) as sde.st_geometry) as vertex_st_geometry
```

Once I do that, I can add the query to ArcMap without issue.